# need more help in Sending welcome email when user logs in to the app first time

Tags: android, email

Please let me know where I need to mention the below codes. I am confused and learner so could you please help me step by step?

```
// set credentials 
Sendgrid mail = new Sendgrid("<sendgrid_username>","<sendgrid_password>"); 
// set email data
mail.setTo("foo@bar.com").setFrom("me@bar.com").setSubject("‌​Subject goes here").setText("Hello World!").setHtml("<strong>Hello World!</strong>"); 
// send your message mail.send();
```

Comment: // set credentials
Sendgrid mail = new Sendgrid("<sendgrid_username>","<sendgrid_password>");

// set email data
mail.setTo("foo@bar.com").setFrom("me@bar.com").setSubject("Subject goes here").setText("Hello World!").setHtml("<strong>Hello World!</strong>");

// send your message
mail.send();

Comment: add your comment code to your question.

Comment: did you resolve the issue? if so please help me because i am facing the same issue